# passing an array from a page php to another one

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I need passing an array from a php page to another one. This array is a multidimensional array that contains the rows of a MySQL query. I put these rows into an array because I think it's the best choice, but I'll take account of advises. Avoiding $_GET, $_POS or cookies and session, do exist other ways to use an array in other php page?

I thought that using file may be a solution, does it worth?
thanks

Comment: Why would you want to avoid `$_GET`, `$_POST`, `$_COOKIE` or `$_SESSION` ?

Comment: This is the point of sessions (server stored) and cookies (client stored).

Comment: Just make another request to the database.

Comment: i'd rather avoid get, post and session becouse if i had a lot of rows it would be complicated working with them... at least for me, a newbie.

Comment: what do you mean with "another request to the database"?

Comment: This is the reason $_SESSION exists.  Not using it because "it would be complicated" is being lazy.  That is the reason it is in PHP is to pass the data through pages, without storing it as a cookie or passing through the $_REQUEST (POST or GET).

Comment: I mean this: you said *is a multidimensional array that contains the rows of a MySQL query*. On the second page build it again the way how you built it first time. What's the reason to pass it between pages? Do you really have a problem with performance and want to cache data or what? If you need to cache something, use caching technologies. Sessions are good when you want to store the state, but not data. For data use cache.

Comment: thanks, it's clear! So i'll look for caching technlogies. thank you again

Answer (score 1):

`$_SESSION` really is the simplest and probably best option, but other options are to look into cache providers (APC, Zend_Cache, Memcached, xcache). Or you could use an external provider such as Firebase (https://www.firebase.com).

Comment: thanks for the answer but why do you say that $_SESSION is the simplest way? i'm supposed to create a $_SESSION variable for every field of my query result... or i can solve this in a quicker way?

Comment: Sessions are really easy, `$_SESSION['allMyStuff'] = $myArrayOfResults;`. But from what you're saying, caching might be the better option. Check out some of the above (there are tons more too). You may even find something like APC is already on your server.

Comment: You can store pretty much anything that can be serialised.